# Inheritance in C++: define variables in parent-child classes

Tags: c++, class, variables, inheritance, parent-child

**Problem**

I am looking for the best way to define the variables in parent-child classes, in order to be called by a pointer to their parent class. 
This is the protocode:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void function() = 0;
};

class A : public Base {
public:
    int a, b;
    A(int a_, int b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {};
    void function() { // do something.. }
};

class B : public Base {
public:
    int a, b;
    B(int a_, int b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {};
    void function() { // do something.. }
};

Base* elements[2] = {
    new A(1,2),
    new B(3,4)
};
```

Since I define `a, b` in both constructors, I might define them in the abstract class `Base`. This way the code should be more efficient and clean. Is this practice correct? How should I define them?

**Possible solutions**

The solution I have in mind is implementing a function that returns for example `a` like this:

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual int return_a() = 0;
};

class A : public Base {
    public:
        int a, b;
        A(int a_, int b_) : a(a_), b(b_) {};
        int return_a() {
        return a;
        }
};

int main(){
    int a = elements[0]->return_a();
}
```

This works, but I am sure it is not an efficient way. Is it better to define `a, b` in the abstract class? Thanks

Comment: If *all* children of `Base` have these `a` and `b` members, then yes defining them in the `Base` class seems like a natural solution. If only *some* children use `a` and `b`, then you could add an intermediate class, like e.g. `struct SubBase : public Base { int a; int b; };` then make your `A` and `B` classes inherit from that class instead.

Comment: And since all members you show are public, you could use `struct` instead (it's the same as `class`, but default visibility is `public` instead of `private`). And if the `a` and `b` members are public, you don't need any "getter" functions for them.

Comment: Public derived methods can directly access public Base attributes.  No 'Base::return_x()' is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this practice correct?

I think this is turning into an opinion-based question-answer. If all your derived classes must include the members `a` and `b`, *then in my opinion*, they should be part of the base class. This way, you are guaranteed that all your derived classes will include the members `a` and `b` and you (or someone else) won't run the risk of forgetting to include them. Furthermore, by including the members in the base class, you save memory by not having to include them at every single derived class. C++'s `virtual` provides you with all the necessary tools to accomplish polymorphism, which is what happens when you create an array of `Base *`.

I would also recommend you use the keyword `override` for the virtual functions that are overridden in the derived class, and the keyword `final` for the derived classes that are not meant to become base classes. You can read the benefits of using those keywords from Scott Meyers Modern C++ book.

```
struct Base
{
    int a, b;

    Base(int a_, int b_) : a(a_) , b(b_)
    {;}

    virtual void function() = 0;
};

struct A : Base // A can be a base class of another class.
{
    A(int a_, int b_) : Base(a_,b_)
    {;}

    void funtion() // this will compile, but it's not going to override the Base::function()
    {;}
};

struct B final : Base // B can never become a base class.
{
    B(int a_, int b_) : Base(a_,b_)
    {;}

    void funtion() override // this won't compile because override will see that we mis-spelled function() 
    {;}
};
```

However, there is no C++ rule that prohibits you from including the members in all of your derived classes.

Also, if all your members are `public`, then you can use a `struct` to avoid having to type `public` inside the classes and in the inheritance method.

```
struct Base
{
    // all members are public
};

struct Derived : Base // public inheritance by default.
{
    // all members are public
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. In this case, I wanted to know the solution with efficiency in mind (as you said, your solution save memory), but in case I would like to ask an opinion-based question, where could I do that?

Comment: @maurocomi: No problem! Again, this is a grey area. The code in your OP was working fine. There was no bug, nor did it contain an illegal instruction. It was purely a question on efficiency. Efficiency however, may vary depending on the needs of the software, so there's no one right solution. This is what turns your question into an opinion based q&a. But then again, I think your question was valid for SO since one had to think of the differences between IS-A, HAS-A, dynamic polymorphism, etc.. Maybe [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be more suitable for next time.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat opinion based, but here is what I think based on the code you have posted.

Since you have made `Base` (from which all classes are derived) an abstract class, it appears that you want to use it as an interface.

In that case, it is better to distinguish between interface inheritance and implementation inheritance. Let `Base` not have any data which means that it would not require any constructors.

This is one of the coding guidelines given by Bjarne Stroustrup titled: [**`When designing a class hierarchy, distinguish between implementation inheritance and interface inheritance`**](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#c129-when-designing-a-class-hierarchy-distinguish-between-implementation-inheritance-and-interface-inheritance).

The reason given is:

> Implementation details in an interface make the interface brittle; that is, make its users vulnerable to having to recompile after changes in the implementation. Data in a base class increases the complexity of implementing the base and can lead to replication of code.

Note that you do not need getters or setters if the data in derived classes is `public`.